# Atom Editor Github Package - what are these icons for?

Tags: github, atom-editor

The [Atom Editor](https://atom.io/) has the [Github package](https://atom.io/packages/github) as standard. There is a nice [documentation page](https://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/github-package/). I've been using the package successfully for quite a while.

But what I cannot work out is just what these icons at locations A, B and C mean when merge conflicts occur.

[image: atom github screenshot]

B and C presumably relate to "mine" and "theirs". Which is which? What icons appear at B or C (sometimes they are different) and what do they mean? I hoped to be able to click one of them and choose 'use my file' or 'use their file', but I can't find that functionality anywhere. Does it exist?

And what icons can appear at location A? Can I click it to do something? Anything?